# Springboot 1.5 No Classe def Found FilterRegistrationBean when trying to test service

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to test a service using Springboot 1.5 I keep getting an exception for No class found for FilterRegestionBean.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ApiServiceSpecTest {

    @Autowired
    ApiService apiService;

    @Test
    public void testGetApis() {
        List<Api> apis = this.apiService.getApis("KFS")
        given(this.apiService.getApis("KFS")).willReturn("some stuff")
    assertThat(!apis.empty)
}
```

My build.gradle looks like:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth', version:'1.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.5.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version:'1.5.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version:'1.5.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version:'1.5.1.RELEASE'
compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version:'1.5.1.RELEASE')
```

I've checked the documentation and feel like I've implemented the example but I can't get it to run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FilterRegistrationBean` was deprecated in Spring boot 1.4.x and most likely removed in Spring boot 1.5 (it only changed package). Your spring-cloud-sleuth dependency is probably based of Spring Boot 1.4 so you get runtime issues when it's trying to instantiate its tracing filters with the `FilterRegistrationBean` class in the old package.

Solution : update you spring-cloud-sleuth dependency to 1.1.2.RELEASE that just got out today : [Release](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/milestone/21?closed=1) and relevant [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/499).

Answer (score 2):

In spring boot 1.5 and later, they have moved the FilterRegistrationBean class. I solved it by changing my import statement from -

> import
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;

to

> import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;

and this worked. This works with spring boot 1.5.1 Release and 1.5.2 Release.

Source - [spring boot FilterReistrationBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html)